# What does ずっと前から mean?

Tags: meaning, syntax

I couldn't understand this structure, so I would like an explanation for this and a translation

日本語を**ずっと前から**勉強してきて、結局はやめた。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translated it means: [this](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E5%89%8D%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89).

And you can break up the parts:

```
ずっと - for a long time
前から - from before
```

Put it all together --> Since a long time ago

> I've studied Japanese from a long time ago, but ended up stopping.

Answer (score 2):

ずっと is an adverb meaning "very".

前 means "past", "before".

ずっと前 means "a long time ago".

ずっと前から  means "since a long time ago".

Answer (score 2):

I'm a native Japanese speaker.
"日本語をずっと前から勉強してきて、結局はやめた。" sounds unnatural. I don't think it is worth learning.
It should be like "日本語をずっと前から勉強してきたが、結局、止めてしまった" or so.

Unfortunately I found the website where the sentence came from contains a lot of unnatural sentences. I'm afraid they were invented by a non-native speaker.